# How does this single phase induction motor run without capacitor?

Tags: motor, ac, inductor, induction-motor, ac-motor

[image]

The motor of the picture has no facility  to connect capacitor. The phase and neutral is directly connected to winding. It works fine on 220 volt 50 Hz AC. Although performance get poor at 190 volts.

As far as I've seen single phase Induction motors have capacitors. Can anyone help me to understand how does this motor works? There are three cables. Two for phase and neutral and the third one is connected to body. So it should be the earth connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably a shaded pole motor ([en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaded-pole_motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaded-pole_motor))
but it is hard to see from the picture.  The bottom winding does seem to have something different in the laminations.

Comment: (If you squint at the picture, you can see a groove on the right of the bottom pole, and a glint on the bend of a blackened conductor of a short winding.)

Comment: The construction of core is similar to shaded pole. I've checked.